# json value in prototype showing up as undefined

Tags: ajax, json, perl, prototypejs

I am using perl modules and cgi scrips on the backend and prototypejs on the front end. I am basically making use of ajax to make a call to the cgi script running on the server which calls another file to put the sent data inside oracle db.

The fronend script is:

```
new Ajax.Request ('ajax-sr-update.cgi', {
    method: 'post',
    asynchronous: 'false',
    parameters: { 
        incident_id: incident_id,
        serial_number: $F('serial_number'),
        cmd: 'Add Serial'
    },
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
    var json = transport.responseJSON();
    if (json) {
        if (json.error_message) {
            //display error message
            } 
        else if (json.incident_id) {            
            //append the output in an alredy displated table
            var new_row = '<tr id="alt-row-'+json.line_number+'">';
                new_row += '<td id="serial_number-'+json.incident_id+'" style="border-left: solid 1px #eeeeee;">'+json.serial_number+'</td>';
                new_row += '<td id="product_number-'+json.incident_id+'">'+json.product_number+'</td>';
                new_row += '<td id="transaction_type-'+json.incident_id+'">'+json.transaction_type+'</td>';
                new_row += '<td id="failure_analysis_flag-'+json.incident_id+'">'+json.failure_analysis_flag+'</td>';
                new_row += '</tr>';
                Element.replace('add-loading-row', new_row);
            } else {
                //display a general error
            }
        } else {
            //display general message
        }

    },
    onFailure: function(data) {
        //display general error message
    }
});
```

The problem that I am facing is all the json returned values show up as undefined when the table is updated, but when I use console.log(json.line_number), I can see the original value. Been working on this thing for past 4 hours, loosing my mind!!.

Things that I have checked:

1. The values are getting out of the database properly, I generated them in the error logs
2. The number of values that are getting generated is also equal to the values needed
3. When I receive the json return it is exactly what is needed.

Comment: thanks a lot it helped me, I was able to see that the values getting returned had extra values attached to it. For example
serial_number was serial_number,

Thank a lot for the idea.

Comment: well, then I'll make that an answer instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try console.log(new_row)?  It may show you something you are missing.